# Implementing search feature on jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, jqgrid

I tried so hard, I don't understand what is missing in my code.

ASP:

```
SEARCHFIELD  = Request.QueryString("SEARCHFIELD")
SEARCHSTRING = Request.QueryString("SEARCHSTRING")
SEARCHOPER   = Request.QueryString("SEARCHOPER")
```

JavaScript:

```
var lastsel;

$(function() {

$("#list").jqGrid({
        url: 'orders.cs.asp?Process=ViewOrders',
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'Get',
        height: '100%',
        colNames: ['Actions','ID #','Customer', 'Date', 'Status','Total','Tracking #'],
        colModel: [
            {name:'Actions', index:'Actions', width:65, sortable:false, search:false},
            {name:'ID', index:'ID', width:30},
            {name:'Customer', index:'Customer', width:150},
            {name:'Date', index:'Date', width:150},
            {name:'TransactStatus', index:'TransactStatus', width:130, editable:true, edittype:"select", editoptions:{value:"Pending:Pending;Awaiting Payment:Awaiting Payment;Awaiting Fulfillment:Awaiting Fulfillment;Awaiting Shipment:Awaiting Shipment;Awaiting Pickup:Awaiting Pickup;Partially Shipped:Partially Shipped;Completed:Completed;Shipped:Shipped;Cancelled:Cancelled;Declined:Declined;Refunded:Refunded"}},
            {name:'Total', index:'Total', width:80, align:"right"}, 
            {name:'ShipTrackingNumber', index:'ShipTrackingNumber', width:126, editable:true}, 
        ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10,20,30],
        sortname: 'Date', 
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        subGrid : true, 
        subGridUrl: 'orders.cs.asp?Process=ViewOrderDetails', 
        subGridModel: [ {
            name: ['Quantity','Product','-', '-', '-'],
            width : [65,350,50,50,50], 
            param: ['invdate']
            } 
        ],
        imgpath: 'js/jqGrid/themes/basic/images',
        onSelectRow: function(id) { 
            if(id && id!==lastsel) {
                $('#list').restoreRow(lastsel); 
                $('#list').editRow(id,true); 
                lastsel=id; 
                } 
            }, 
        loadComplete: function(){ 
            var ids = jQuery("#list").getDataIDs(); 
            for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){ 
                var cl = ids[i]; 
                be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' onclick=jQuery('#list').editRow("+cl+"); ></ids>"; 
                se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=jQuery('#list').saveRow("+cl+"); />"; 
                ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=jQuery('#list').restoreRow("+cl+"); />"; 
                jQuery("#list").setRowData(ids[i],{Actions:be+se+ce}) 
            } 
        }, 
        editurl: "orders.cs.asp?Process=EditOrder",
}).navGrid("#pager",{edit:true,add:false,del:false});   

});
```

Comment: You need to tell use what you intend and what is going wrong.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438659/how-to-implement-search-on-jqgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438659/how-to-implement-search-on-jqgrid)

Comment: It is not working and it is not giving any errors. I thought demo website is a best way to show what is going wrong.

http://refinethetaste.com/html/cp/?Section=orders&Process=ViewOrders

http://refinethetaste.com/html/cp/orders.cs.asp?Process=ViewOrders&ROWS=10&SIDX=Date&SORD=asc&SEARCHFIELD=ID&SEARCHSTRING=1&SEARCHOPER=equal

Comment: It might help if the xml you send to the jqGrid contains some orders, now its doesn't contain any data to fill the jqGrid

Comment: Indeed, I entered 11 records for you to see it functioning. Something odd is happening, I can see the rows when viewing the database, but cant see them in the view orders page??

Comment: oh and I fixed it, you can view both xml and jqgrid page.

jqgrid:
http://refinethetaste.com/html/cp/?Section=orders&Process=ViewOrders

xml:
http://refinethetaste.com/html/cp/orders.cs.asp?Process=ViewOrders&ROWS=10&SIDX=Date&SORD=asc

xml with sample search:
http://refinethetaste.com/html/cp/orders.cs.asp?Process=ViewOrders&ROWS=10&SIDX=Date&SORD=asc&SEARCHFIELD=ID&SEARCHSTRING=1&SEARCHOPER=equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i try your search for example, get all the customers where the customer column contains Yavuz.

Then I get the following error (i can see this with firebug): **An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.**

There's propably something wrong with your **SQL statement**.

Comment: I will faint now. I forgot to use ' after % ... Torres thank you sooo much! You just saved my mental health.