# How to implement search in jqgrid in php controller

Tags: php, jqgrid

I have been playing around recently with jqgrid and am at loss on how to implement search in my controller using PHP (Zend).
I came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438659/how-to-implement-search-on-jqgrid/758419#758419) that is quite similar to the answer am looking for but what I need is the PHP version not ASP.NET.

Comment: The code would essentially be the same; can you work through a first-cut of it, and post some code if you run into trouble?

Comment: am on it.will edit my question once I get somewhere