# jqGrid: search box is disabled 2

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Here is one more example I'm fighting with...

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'AjaxFunctions.asmx/TestMethod',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    //postdata: { _search: "true" },
    multiselect: true,
    //postData: { "filters": jsonData},
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
        if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    jsonReader: {
        root: function (obj) { return obj.d.rows; },
        page: function (obj) { return obj.d.page; },
        total: function (obj) { return obj.d.total; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.d.records; }
    },
    // you can also use following more simple form of jsonReader instead:
    // jsonReader: { root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", total: "d.total",
    //               records: "d.records", id: "d.names" }
    colNames:['Name', 'Title'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'name', label: 'Name', width: 250 },
        { name: 'title', label: 'Title', width: 250 }
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 300],
    sortname: 'name',
    sortorder: "asc",
    pager: $("#pager"),
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    height: 250,
    imgpath: '../css/images',
    caption: 'My first grid'
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true});
```

});

My problem is when i click on search button it shows search box, but **disable** the grid and **search box** as well.

Comment: i think i m missing any js file, plz tell me is there ny additional js should b included 4 searching/filtering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `overlay:false` property of the search options:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false},{},{},{},
                  {multipleSearch:true,overlay:false});
```

the jqGrid will not create overlay over the grid and the search dialog will bot block the grid.

I suppose that your main problem is in the list of jqGrid components which you selected as you [downloaded](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) the jquery.jqGrid.min.js. The file should contain at least grid.base.js; grid.common.js; grid.formedit.js; jquery.searchFilter.js components. If you open jquery.jqGrid.min.js in the text editor you will see all jqGrid components in the comment (search for "* Modules:" text). If you will not find one from the modules in your copy of jquery.jqGrid.min.js you should [download](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) the jqGrid one more time selecting more modules.

Another possible reason can be some conflict in CSS which you use. Try reproduce the problem on possible pure web page and then go step by step to your current page with all CSS.

Comment: heyyyyyyyy Oleg u such a sweet heart:) u resolved my problem i am so happy thanQ thanQ thanQ thanQ thanQ thanQ thanQ thanQ thanQ vry much ur "suggestion "conflict in CSS" worked 4 me, i ws missing searchFilter.css....

Comment: @Ankit: You should inclued more jqGrid components. For example `jqDnR.js`. Another one `jqModal.js` can be also needed depend on another settings.